# How do you debug pythonic GUI programs?

Tags: python, user-interface, debugging, pdb

I want to debug a pythonic program, such as [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/). Normally, I was using [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) to debug from the console, but when I use pdb with pythonic GUI programs, the GUI part (canvas or what the heck it is) freezes and it's really very hard to debug in that way.

Any suggestions for debugging pythonic GUI programs? How do you do it?

Comment: Does the standard logging module not meet your needs?

Comment: @wberry can you give any examples or links for using the standard logging module while debugging a pythonic GUI program?

Comment: For a GUI based one-liner hack, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65782172/11392807

Answer (score 0):

I would place calls to `logging.debug` at the top of each event handler function/method in my GUI code that represents a "user action", i.e. mouse clicks, enter key.  Also any high-level function that updates the view would have a `logging.debug` call at the beginning.  These log messages would report any important information used in the function/method.  Because the messages are logged at `DEBUG` level, you can turn them on/off with a simple configuration change.

Alternatively, while unsophisticated, it might be faster to forget even the `logging` module and put in `print` statements temporarily until you find the problem.

Here's some code I wrote to initialize the `logging` module with a rotating log file:

```
import pytz

timestamp_detailed_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z'

def detailed_format(date):
  u"Given a datetime object return a detailed representation including fractional seconds and time zone"
  return unicode(date.strftime(timestamp_detailed_format))

def localize_epoch_time(epoch_time, timezone=pytz.UTC):
  u"Given an epoch time return an accurate, timezone-aware datetime object"
  t = localtime(epoch_time)
  epochdt = datetime(*(t[:6] + (int((epoch_time - long(epoch_time)) * 1000000),))).astimezone(timezone)
  if hasattr(timezone, 'normalize'):  # pytz tzinfo objects have this
    return timezone.normalize(epochdt)
  else: # tzinfo object not from pytz module
    return epochdt

class TimezoneAwareFormatter(logging.Formatter):
  u"custom log formatter using timezone-aware timestamps"
  def __init__(self, logformat=None, timezone=pytz.UTC):
    logging.Formatter.__init__(self, logformat)
    self._timezone = timezone
  def formatTime(self, record, _=None):
    u"times will be formatted as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ssssss TZ"
    return detailed_format(localize_epoch_time(record.created, self._timezone))

def simple_log_file(filename, logname=None, level=logging.NOTSET,
                    threshold=10485760, generations=2, quiet=False, timezone=pytz.UTC):
  u"initialize logging API for a simple generational log file, return logger object"
  formatter = TimezoneAwareFormatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', timezone)
  handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename, 'a', threshold, generations, 'UTF-8')
  handler.setFormatter(formatter)
  logger = logging.getLogger(logname)
  logger.addHandler(handler)
  logger.setLevel(level)
  if not quiet: logger.info(u'Logging to this destination has started')
  return logger
```